# How to copy all files and folders from tfs to remote path if I know source location?

Tags: tfs

I have one folder on TFS server that has around 10 sub-folders. Its structure looks like below.

```
Top Folder ($/MyProject/Top)
|-- Sub 1 ($/MyProject/Top/Sub1)
    |-- file1-1.txt
|-- Sub 2 ($/MyProject/Top/Sub2)
    |-- file2-1.txt
    |-- file2-1.txt
|-- Sub 3 ($/MyProject/Top/Sub3)
|-- Sub 4 ($/MyProject/Top/Sub4)
    |-- file4-1.txt
    |-- file4-1.txt
|-- Sub 5 ($/MyProject/Top/Sub5)
    |-- file5-1.txt
```

Right now I create a custom workflow activity to copy file-by-file from source to destination. I want to copy all files and folder in Top Folder to a remote path. How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique would be to create a batch file where you call [`tf get`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to do the remote copy.